# Unit Test - Assert object returned by a controller action

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I check if the value returned as part of that OkObjectResult has a count of 2 without changing any code in the controller action?

Here is my controller action

```
public IActionResult GetUserNames()
{
    var users = _repository.GetUsers();
    return Ok(users.Select(u => u.Name));
}
```

My unit test looks like this

```
[Fact]
public void GetUserNames_ValidRequest_ShouldReturnOk()
{
    _repository
        .Setup(r => r.GetUsers())
        .Return(new List<User> 
            {
                new User { Name = "SomeRandomName" },
                new User { Name = "SomeRandomName2" }  
            });

    var result = _controller.GetUserNames();

    result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
    // Code to check if 2 names are returned
}
```

I am using Mock and FluentAssertions in my unit test.

Comment: Rather meaningless test. All this does is check if one of your controller's methods returns an Ok result. Nothing to do with having a valid request. Also unles some complete idiot comes along and edits your code so it returns a non success status code it's a pointless test case - you should have at least some level of confidence in your colleagues. I'd be more worried about testing actual business logic rather than control flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var objectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<List<string>>(objectResult.Value);
Assert.Equal(2, model.Count);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Saved me 99999 hours debugging.